# jQuery ) SyntaxError: missing : after property id)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery in my page that keeps giving the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Code

```
        <div id='content1'  >
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var theme = getDemoTheme();
        var source = [
            "Suppliers",
            "Global Networks",
            "Supplier Networks",
            "Supplier Prices",
            "Supplier Data Import",
            "Supplier Target Price Export"
        ];
        // Create a jqxDropDownList
        $("#jqxWidget1").jqxDropDownList({ source: source, selectedIndex: 0, width: '200',margin-top:'0px', height: '25', theme: theme });
    });
</script>
<div id='jqxWidget1'>
</div>
```

Firebug says it is on this line:

Comment: please make sure you close the top most div(<div id='content1'  >) by placing </div> at the last.

Answer (score 3):

In the json option passed to `jqxDropDownList`, you have a key `margin-top`, since it has a `-` it has to be wrapped in `""`

Try

```
$("#jqxWidget1").jqxDropDownList({ source: source, selectedIndex: 0, width: '200',"margin-top":'0px', height: '25', theme: theme });
```

Comment: can you explain, please, why this should fix? Thanks.

Comment: @DJHell was typing it